# Why are my SharePoint downloads not completing for outside users?

Tags: windows-server-2003, sharepoint, wss-3.0, document-management

I am using WSS 3.0 with Microsoft Server 2003.

I am running into the following problem.

On a pretty frequent basis, outside users are having trouble downloading documents.

Some downloads are completing while the download is still incomplete.  So for instance, a PDF is a 17MB file.  If I download it from within the office, all 17MBs are downloaded and it opens.  If I download it from an outside connection, it may download anywhere from 5-10 MB of the file and then say it is complete.  When these partial downloads are opened, it gives the user the error, this file is corrupt and cannot be repaired.

I have solved this problem on some of the occasions by simply deleting the document and uploading a new copy of the document.  This does not always work.

Are there known bugs?  Are the Internet settings that need to be modified on the outside user's machine?  Does anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Our firewall was scanning files before it let users download them.  Turning this setting off seemed to fix the problem.